# Extending URIs with 2 queries (i.e. 'viewauthorbooks.php?authorid=4' AND 'orderby=returndate") Possible?

Tags: php, mysql, uri

I have a link in my system as displayed above; 'viewauthorbooks.php?authorid=4' which works fine and generates a page displaying the books only associated with the particular author. However I am implementing another feature where the user can sort the columns (return date, book name etc) and I am using the ORDER BY SQL clause. I have this also working as required for other pages, which do not already have another query in the URI. But for this particular page there is already a paramter returned in the URL, and I am having difficulty in extending it.

When the user clicks on the a table column title I'm getting an error, and the original author ID is being lost!!

This is the URI link I am trying to use:

```
<th><a href="viewauthorbooks.php?authorid=<?php echo $row['authorid']?>&orderby=returndate">Return Date</a></th>
```

This is so that the data can be sorted in order of Return Date. When I run this; the author ID gets lost for some reason, also I want to know if I am using correct layout to have 2 parameters run in the address? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the layout is correct.  Of course it's possible to have even more than 2 parameters in the query string
you have to check resulting query string (just take look into your address bar after click), there must be something like `viewauthorbooks.php?authorid=22&orderby=returndate`. If number is lost, you have to check it's source - $row['authorid'] variable.

Comment: Hi Col. Shrapnel...I managed to retrieve the authorid back into the URI, by adding this after my query;

$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

However, for some strange reason, the first book in the list disappears!!?? After the table headings have been declared, I again declare the row variable, could this be messsing things up? I have this: 'while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))'

Comment: @Jess ummm. probably you have to find another source for your author idd. Try to remove that additional mysql_fetch_array($result); and use $_GET['authorid'] instead of $row['authorid'] in your hyperlink

Comment: IGNORE! Instead of echoing the $row variable for author ID, I used '<?php echo $authorid?>' as the link, and it carries the authorid just as required :D:D

Comment: Yes I did use $_GET method as you have stated also! Forgot to mention that part. Thanks for your help Colnel

Answer (score 0):

you have to use `&amp;` and sanitize your output, but apart from that it's correct ;)

Comment: @knittl why he have to? it works fine with "&", only problem is validation.

Comment: becaue `&` will start an html-entity. you'll have problems, when your variables start with `uuml`, `amp` or any other entity. and you want to have valid pages after all ;)